# PopUp Menus in a custom GUI API?

Tags: c++, api, user-interface, memory-management

I have made my own GUI API for games. One assumption that must be made is the user may want to use a derived version of a Widget I have made.

An example of how I dealt with this with ToolTips is, the user allocates a new ToolTip and sets a global one for the GUI. Ex: getGui().setToolTip(customToolTip);

The GUI then calls toolTip->show() when necessary. The problem with menus in general is that you can have many of them appearing at a given time.

I also would hate to have the user implement an interface:

```
PopUpFactory::createPopUp()
PopUpFactory::destroyPopup()
```

How is this usually dealt with? Who or how is the memory also managed for these?

There is always the option of limiting to something like 9 nested menus and have the user set an array of 9 PopUps but that seems messy.

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a virtual `BaseMenu` class or something that handles the memory allocation/deallocation, and then simply have the consumer extend that class? That way, the memory management would be encapsulated away deep in your code, and the consumer wouldn't have to implement any methods (because they're unlikely to ever have to override the standard memory management).

Comment: @Cody Gray could you give me an example, I'm not sure exactly what you mean?